# Can we have multliple routing.yml files in a single module?

Tags: 8, routes

I have more than 50 menus which I need to create custom.
as per the module structure, we need to create routing.yml in root folder.
but I want to do something like this below:

```
   myModule
      -  products(folder)
              - routing.yml
              - src(folder)
                - productController  
      -  brands(folder)
              - routing.yml
              - src(folder)
                - brandsController.php    
      - myModule.info.yml
      - myModule.module
```

is it way to do achive something like this.

I just want to make code seperation and avoid to add all routes in routing.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding multiple routing files, you can define products, brands as modules inside your main module and then can define routing file for each of them like what is done in aggregator module in core. 
[image: aggregator-module-core]

Answer (score 1):

The routing.yml can split by multiple files. You can include separate routing files in your routing.yml file.

```
acme_demo_user:
  resource: "@acmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing/user_routing.yml"
  prefix: /user
acme_demo_vehicles:
  resource: "@acmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing/vehicles_routing.yml"
  prefix: /vehicles
.............
.............
```

It would works in symfony not sure in drupal 8, I hope it would works in drupal 8 too.
Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355385/symfony2-splitting-routing-yml-in-multiple-files

Answer (score 0):

the included routing files in a single file reouting.yml does not work under drupal because in drupal there is not the notion of bundle

I tested by passing the module name and also the namespace but it does not work

```
myroute_form:
  resource: "@module_name/routing/salesforce_front_routing.yml"

myroute_form2:
  resource: "@Drupal/module_name/routing/salesforce_front_routing.yml"
```