# Splitting routing.yml in multiple files

Tags: 8, routes

I have a **my_module.routing.yml** file and because of I have multi entity in my module its too big and not pretty.

Is there any way to split it for each entity and include them in one file like [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355385/symfony2-splitting-routing-yml-in-multiple-files), I use below code but it's not work in drupal 8.

```
acme_demo_user:
  resource: "@acmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing/user_routing.yml"
```

I also use absolute path for yml file but it's not work.

Comment: Use [DefaultHtmlRouteProvider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Routing%21DefaultHtmlRouteProvider.php/class/DefaultHtmlRouteProvider/8.6.x) or extend this class to customize the routes.

Comment: tnx @4k4 I see this but is there any way with yaml file?

Comment: No, the code to discover those yaml files is Drupal specific, so the Symfony docs are not valid here, see Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder

Comment: [This](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211782/drupal-8-can-we-add-multliple-routing-yml-file-in-a-single-module) post says that you can split routing.yml in multiple files, or you can do something a little bit alternate.